# Taking user input and plugging it into dynamically allocating array, Beginner C++

Tags: c++

```
string firstname, lastname;
string phonenumber, email;
cout << "What is the first of the person that you would like to add? : ";
cin >> firstname;


cout << "What is the last of the person that you would like to add? : ";
cin >> lastname;


cout << firstname << " " << lastname << endl;
cout << "What is the phone number of that person? : ";
cin >> phonenumber;
```

I need help taking this user input and plugging it into an array. I honestly do not know how to do that, if I could get some help on that it would be great!

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` will help

Comment: [Find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start reading about *structures* before you start wondering about "dynamic arrays". And if you have a good book, then it will explain dynamic memory allocation as well.

Comment: I understand how to use arrays, that have a fixed value, but my professor told me that we had to do this( for a programming assignment), also using structs, should i read up on those as well?

Answer (score 3):

Create a struct named Record as follows

```
struct Record
{
   string firstName, lastName,phone; //etc 
};
```

If you know how many records you want to enter then you have to create an array of Record as follows

```
Record PersonInfo[5];
```

Now each index of PersonInfo let say PersonInfo[2] is a complete Record and you can access there fields like

```
PersonInfo[2].phone = "5655567" //etc
```

Now if you want to create array of Record but don't know the size then your best bet for now is to use a vector like follows. A vector is an array of changable size. You need to include the following header

```
#include<vector>
```

After wards you can do the following

```
vector<Record> PersonInfo //thats how vectors are declared
```

The name between <> bractes tell of what type you want a vector of ,you can write int as well. 
Following is how you add items to a vector

```
Record r1,r2; // just for example
PersonInfo.push_back(r1);
PersonInfo. push_back(r2);
```

you may add any number of items in it and you can access them just like array as follows

```
PersonInfo[0] .lastName // its actually r1.lastName and so on
```

This may seem difficult for now you may want to learn vectors and their operations before going for dynamic memory allocation which requires that you understand what pointers are. I don't know that you know about pointers and how to use them that is why I reffered you vectors